# Where do I put my api key in Google Cloud PHP Language Client?

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform, nlp, key

I am trying to perform a sentiment analysis with the Google Cloud PHP language client from this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries

In the documentation they say this should work with a plain api key: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

I already tried a couple of ways on how to set the api key (plain api key, no oauth), but I am always getting the error: "The request is missing a valid API key."

Here some of my tries:

```
// Instantiates a client
    $language = new LanguageClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
        'key' => $key,
        'developerKey' => $key,
        'api_key' => $key
    ]);
    $language->setDeveloperKey($key);

    // Detects the sentiment of the text
    $annotation = $language->analyzeSentiment($texttoanalyze);
    $sentiment = $annotation->sentiment();

    echo 'Text: ' . $text . 'Sentiment: ' . $sentiment['score'] . ', ' . $sentiment['magnitude'];
```

Comment: not sure if this helps as I'm not a PHP guy - but the access token needs to be described in the header - look into options for obtaining an access token using OAUTH2

Comment: I now tried the standard method with a service account like described here: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-language/v0.16.1/guides/authentication

setting the environment variable export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[path to my key file] did not help. I am still getting the same error

I think when using the google client (composer require google/cloud-language) it should not be necessary to set a header explicitly.

Comment: If you run this quickstart - https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php , do you have the same error? I just tried it with setting the environmental variable and it worked well. Usually with the client library you authenticate with the environmental variable or using the credentials from the JSON file. The API key is usually required when you send a POST request to the API directly.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured out how to perform a plain api call without using the client library like this:
POST https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=API_KEY

like described here: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/documents/analyzeEntities

I could resolve the issue with the authentication for the client library by adding the parameter keyFilePath to the config of the LanguageClient like this:

```
$language = new LanguageClient([
        'projectId' => 'my-project-id',
        'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/my/keyfile.json'
    ]);
```